# LIMIT by GROUP without omitting the duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pdo

I have this somewhat complex query (stripped down version):

```
SELECT    a.item_id,
          a.title,
          a.series,
          c.title AS manufacturer_title
FROM      catalog_items AS a
JOIN      catalog_franchises AS c ON a.manufacturer_id = c.franchise_id
JOIN      catalog_franchises AS e ON a.game_id = e.franchise_id
WHERE     e.franchise_id = 6
          AND a.valid = TRUE
          AND c.valid = TRUE
          AND e.valid = TRUE
ORDER BY  c.title, a.series, a.title
```

The important fields that I'm attempting to focus on are `c.title` and `a.series`. So for sake of brevity this query returns:

```
item_id      series      manufacturer_title
46           2           fantasy flight games
63           1           gaming heads
64           1           gaming heads
33           2           reaper miniatures
124          1           triforce
125          1           triforce
45           1           triforce
43           1           usaopoly
```

What I'm attempting to do is add a `LIMIT` based a unique combination of these fields... If I add: `GROUP BY c.title, a.series` it gives me the unique groups:

```
item_id      series      manufacturer_title
46           2           fantasy flight games
63           1           gaming heads
33           2           reaper miniatures
124          1           triforce
43           1           usaopoly
```

But I want *all* the rows, limited by those groups. So if the limit is 3, I want all items within the first 3 groups:

```
item_id      series      manufacturer_title
46           2           fantasy flight games
63           1           gaming heads
64           1           gaming heads
33           2           reaper miniatures
```

I hope that makes sense. How can I modify my query to achieve this?

Comment: What are the primary and unique keys?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel every field with `_id` at the end is a primary / unique key.

Comment: That is an abuse of `group by`; it is intended for aggregation, not "semi-distinctness".

Comment: @Uueerdo I am open to a non-abusive solution if you have one.

Comment: Just pointing out, in not so many words, that use of `group by` results in an effectively random choice of item_id for each group (from among the item id values for each group); and is only allowed in MySQL (and it's newer versions are configured disable it by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your original query to get the first 3 groups:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.title, a.series
FROM      catalog_items AS a
JOIN      catalog_franchises AS c ON a.manufacturer_id = c.franchise_id
JOIN      catalog_franchises AS e ON a.game_id = e.franchise_id
WHERE     e.franchise_id = 6
          AND a.valid = TRUE
          AND c.valid = TRUE
          AND e.valid = TRUE
ORDER BY  c.title, a.series
LIMIT 3
```

Use that as subquery in the FROM clause (derived table) to limit your result to the 3 groups:

```
SELECT    a.item_id,
          a.title,
          a.series,
          c.title AS manufacturer_title
FROM      catalog_items AS a
JOIN      catalog_franchises AS c ON a.manufacturer_id = c.franchise_id
JOIN      catalog_franchises AS e ON a.game_id = e.franchise_id
-- begin injected code 
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.title, a.series
    FROM      catalog_items AS a
    JOIN      catalog_franchises AS c ON a.manufacturer_id = c.franchise_id
    JOIN      catalog_franchises AS e ON a.game_id = e.franchise_id
    WHERE     e.franchise_id = 6
              AND a.valid = TRUE
              AND c.valid = TRUE
              AND e.valid = TRUE
    ORDER BY  c.title, a.series
    LIMIT 3
) x ON a.series = x.series AND c.title = x.title
-- end injected code 
WHERE     e.franchise_id = 6
          AND a.valid = TRUE
          AND c.valid = TRUE
          AND e.valid = TRUE
ORDER BY  c.title, a.series, a.title
```

This is essentialy the same as Uueerdo suggested, but using a JOIN instead of a `WHERE .. IN ..` condition.

Comment: trying to wrap my head around this one, but it appears to be returning duplicate results / putting items alongside manufacturers that they don't belong to...

Comment: "trying to wrap my head around this one" - me too ;-)

Comment: @mistermartin I tried to remove some JOINs, but I guess you need to use all three tables in the inner and outer query.

Answer (score 2):

You can select and limit the groups in a subquery first, and join that back to the table for the final results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a2.series, c2.title
FROM catalog_items AS a2
JOIN catalog_franchises AS c2 ON a2.manufacturer_id = c2.franchise_id
JOIN catalog_franchises AS e2 ON a2.game_id = e2.franchise_id
WHERE e2.franchise_id = 6
    AND a2.valid = TRUE
    AND c2.valid = TRUE
    AND e2.valid = TRUE
ORDER BY  c2.title, a2.series
LIMIT 3
```

just add this to the original query's WHERE:

`AND (a.series, c.title) IN (query above)`

*Note: Yes, is does result in almost duplicating the original query within itself; but that is often how these kinds of queries end up needing to be.*

Answer (score 1):

Would getting the results in a single column help?  If so, you can use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.item_id) as items,
       a.series, c.title AS manufacturer_title
FROM catalog_items a JOIN
     catalog_franchises c
     ON a.manufacturer_id = c.franchise_id JOIN
     catalog_franchises e
     ON a.game_id = e.franchise_id
WHERE e.franchise_id = 6 AND
      a.valid = TRUE AND
      c.valid = TRUE AND
      e.valid = TRUE
GROUP BY a.series, c.title
ORDER BY c.title, a.series;
```

Although you can get the results in separate rows, this is harder than it should be in MySQL (pre-v8).  This is a relatively simple solution, if it meets your needs.

EDIT:

One way to get what you want uses variables:

```
SELECT ist.*
FROM (SELECT ist.*,
             (@rn := if(@st = concat_ws(':', a.series, manufacturer_title), @rn,
                        if(@st := concat_ws(':', a.series, manufacturer_title), @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM (SELECT a.item_id, a.series, c.title AS manufacturer_title
            FROM catalog_items a JOIN
                 catalog_franchises c
                 ON a.manufacturer_id = c.franchise_id JOIN
                 catalog_franchises e
                 ON a.game_id = e.franchise_id
            WHERE e.franchise_id = 6 AND
                  a.valid = TRUE AND
                  c.valid = TRUE AND
                  e.valid = TRUE
            ORDER BY c.title, a.series
           ) ist CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @st := '') params
      ) ist
WHERE rn <= 3;
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but I believe having separate rows would be more appropriate to simplify how I'm working with the data. If that is possible.